# Maven Parent - child project issue

Tags: maven

I have parent project - selenium and child project as project 1 , my intention is to have all the reusable classes in parent and test in child.When i try to run the test from child project i got the below error , could any one please help me."Failed to execute goal on project project1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.aero:project1:pom:
1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.automation:parentproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT".I tried mvn clean and mvn install at parent project first and child project then executed mvn surefire:test but got the above exception.
    Note: When i first build the parent project it doesnot generated the .jar file in the .M2 path

pom.xmL
    -------

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>project1</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Child pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>

        <groupId>com.automation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Mentioned above the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

1- you child pom referencing the wrong parent artifact.

2- direct dependency to "parentproject" should be removed, since its parent and not a dependency.

Parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.automation</groupId>
<artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>project1</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><--!You are not using the Java bindings (i.e. Python, C#, or Ruby) and would like to use HtmlUnit Driver-->
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>

    <groupId>com.automation</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>project1</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       ...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

hope this helps

Comment: <scope>test</scope> is already mentioned in the child project and still the same issue

Comment: Yes i have updated child pom , can you please have a look

Comment: as i can see the upper pom is not the parent of the lower one. The parent of child pom should be "<artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>". where this artifact "<artifactId>selenium</artifactId>" comes from?

Comment: Sorry Hisham i just renamed the project since it is confidential in that way i have mentioned wrongly.But this is my scenario please have a look

Comment: If i remove the "direct dependency to "parentproject" then how can i extend the reusable from parent to child.I use intellij ide if i hover it says Add parent dependency and if do that i could extend the class in child project.But how could i refer the classes in parent project without adding dependency.Please help me

Comment: you inheriting from the parentproject. this why it called parent

Comment: Fine i understand then how could i solve the above error

Comment: you have to run "mvn clean install" on the parent only , this will excute the child also because its aggregated as module.

Comment: Thanks Hisham for your reply but i now i made parent to handle external dependecies and added one more module as framework(added reusable classes) and refered that in all child.It works now